# Retrieving the last record in each group without primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table to record user last login detail

```
event_name userID value                  created_at
-------------------------------------------------------------
last_login 12    2016-06-02 11:06:29    2016-06-02 11:06:29 
last_login 12    2016-06-02 10:16:11    2016-06-02 10:16:11     
last_login 14    2016-06-02 10:11:13    2016-06-02 10:11:13     
last_login 17    2016-05-02 10:16:29    2016-05-02 10:16:29     
last_login 14    2016-05-02 10:15:11    2016-06-02 10:15:11
```

Expected result:

```
event_name userID value                  created_at
-------------------------------------------------------------
last_login 12    2016-06-02 11:06:29    2016-06-02 11:06:29 
last_login 14    2016-06-02 10:11:13    2016-06-02 10:11:13     
last_login 17    2016-05-02 10:16:29    2016-05-02 10:16:29
```

I want to grab this table information group by UserId , I made it order by created_at and showing value in timesAgo fromat(e.g 1hour ago) but I amm not getting latest record on using group by for example , for userID = 12 I am getting value =2016-06-02 10:16:11 instead of value = 2016-06-02 11:06:29

Comment: Also specify the expected result!

Comment: What is your SQL-Query?

Comment: What DB data type are you using for `value`?

Comment: value is a `varchar(512)`, as I am storing values of some other event as well, while `created_at is DATETIME`

Comment: Why in expected result for user 14 used not the highest value?

Comment: I think it is using the highest value, there is a difference of month

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve this with `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE s.created_at > t.created_at
                    AND s.userID = t.userID)
```

Comment: I guess I did not make myself clear in question, I have added the expected result to make it more clear what I needed

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand, why one time you pick the largest date, and one time the smallest?! @KuldeepDangi

Comment: records are grouped by `USERID`

Comment: It worked :) thanks, is this query will work OK on millions of record ? or for performance should I must add primary key ?

Comment: Hard to say, always better to add primary keys and indexes. @KuldeepDangi

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

First i get the max from created_at and userID and then i join to get the hole row

```
SELECT d.* FROM (
  SELECT 
      userID, MAX(created_at)  AS created_at
  FROM
      tablename 
  GROUP BY userID ) AS `keys`
LEFT JOIN tablename d ON 
  d.userID = `keys`.userID
  AND 
 d.created_at = `keys`.created_at;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT d.* FROM (
    ->   SELECT
    ->       userID, MAX(created_at)  AS created_at
    ->   FROM
    ->       tablename
    ->   GROUP BY userID ) AS `keys`
    -> LEFT JOIN tablename d ON
    ->   d.userID = `keys`.userID
    ->   AND
    ->  d.created_at = `keys`.created_at;
+--------+----------------------------+
| userID | created_at                 |
+--------+----------------------------+
|      1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 |
|      2 | 2016-06-03 13:16:07.000000 |
+--------+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Comment: running this query in mysql resulting in syntax error `near AS keys`

Comment: @Kuldeep Dangi - sorry - my mistake - first: keys is a keyword and must backquoted or use a other alias. second: i forgot a alias for max(created_date). I have change my answer. please test it again - sorry